# Dialogflow - Force to detect the format [Date][Number] as Date & Time

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am developing a bot using Dialogflow and I ask my user for the date and time.
I have 2 entities that are `@sys.date` and `@sys.time`
They might reply like "Monday 4pm". Sometimes they just reply "Monday 4". What I expect is it will extract Monday is sys.date and 4 is sys.time. But it is looking for the next Monday 4th and only extracts @sys.date which is Mon 4th, @sys.time is empty.

How can I force Dialogflow to detect that the number 4 is the time, not the number of date?

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you set both of the parameters/entities as "required" you can add a prompt to the user for the information. This will allow them to enter the data separately so the bot doesn't confuse the 2 together. It would go something like this:
bot: "What is the date?"
customer: "Monday"
bot: "What time?"
customer: "4PM"
[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CrTS.png)